# How to access .json file from one directory to another of same project in robot automationframework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjjeY.png)

Want to access **config.json(Framework/Config/QA/config.json)** file from **apiRequest.robot(Framework/Keywords/API/apiRequest.robot)**
Tried below two ways but not working

**${JSON_Path_config}            Get File    C:/Project/Framework/Config/QA/config.json**

**${JSON_Path_config}           ${CURDIR}${/}..\..\Config\QA\config**

If I am keeping file in current directory then I can access it as below

**${JSON_Path_config}          ${CURDIR}${/}config.json**

But want to access it from another folder

Comment: I have a similar scenario and I have used paths like this: `${JSON_Path_config}     ${CURDIR}../../Config/QA/config` Robot Framework is happy with slashes.